# Android: Convert .extensions to Lower/Upper case

Tags: android, json, string, extension-methods

Tnx in advance for helping . I want to convert my dot file extensions into Lower-case from Upper-case. E.g: **ABCD.JPG >> ABCD.jpg , xyz.PNG >> xyz.png**

```
 if ( attachemtnDescription.toString().endsWith(".JPG") || attachemtnDescription.toString().endsWith(".jpg"))  {
                                        attachmentPreviewImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_support_attachment_image);
```

Because I'm having lots of attachment types to declare, so its hectic to declare all types of attachment both in Upper and Lower case, so I want to reduce my code .

I am having one method to convert from Upper/Lower conversions but **how to implement the same** ... Please help with the same.

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);

String input;

input = edit.getText().toString();
input = input.toLowerCase(); //converts the string to lowercase
   or 
input = input.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: This may help you for renaming. stackoverflow.com/a/2896829/1977021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `attachemtnDescription.toString().toUpperCase().endsWith(".JPG")` will solve your problem, convert the file name to uppercase/lowercase before do the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this , hope it will help you guys too .

```
if (attachmentName.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || attachmentName.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                                        attachmentPreviewImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_support_attachment_image);
```

Use " **.toLowerCase()** " or "**.toUpperCase()**" .